# Bootstrap CSS Field Prefix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstraps Field Prefix and having some trouble with the sizing.

Is there a way to manually adjust the sizes of these so they are even?

[image]

Even if I add a space after name, it then makes that one too long.

Comment: examine the css and do it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is of the class: input-group-addon you can add this to your customisation file:

```
.input-group-addon:first-child {
    min-width: 100px !important;
}
```

or whatever you want it to be. Or you create an additional class and add this to the element.

```
<span class="imput-group-addon customClass">Name</span>

.customClass {
    min-width: 100px !important;
}
```

Check in the source what class it is - input-group-addon is just a guess by looking at the source of: http://getbootstrap.com/components/   - Basic Examples / Input Groups.

Comment: I tried this and couldnt get it to work right - tried to edit he existing class and create a new one but they dont change in size

Comment: Try the following in your custom css: .input-group-addon {
 min-width: 140px !important;
}   ... This works for me.